# How to create RDMS like data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

I've a records like below

```
100, Jon, USA
200, Bob, UK
300, Tom, FR
```

And a schema for above records are

```
ID, Name, Country
```

How can I create a data strcuture in java, where I could iterate them with the help of schema name ?

My data structure should look like `MyDataRecords<Record>`.
And when I iterate over it, I could get values like `Record.getID(), Record.getName(), Record.getCountry()`

Comment: This site is not a do-my-homework service. Post here only when you have a specific technical programming issue. And always search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: @BasilBourque I’m looking for an idea how to develop this data structure.